# a code to implement a simple traffic signal and also display on LCD which color is ON?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, lcd, code-review

I have tried code given below for simple traffic signal and also display on LCD which color is ON, but it didn't work. Please me to make it work.

```cpp
int red = 10;
int yellow = 9;
int green = 8;
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup(){
    pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
    changeLights();
    delay(1500);
}

void changeLights(){
    lcd.print("red");
    digitalWrite(yellow,LOW );
    digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(green,LOW );
    delay(3000);
    lcd.print("yellow");
    digitalWrite(yellow,HIGH );
    digitalWrite(red,LOW );
    digitalWrite(green,LOW );
    delay(3000);
    lcd.print("green");
    digitalWrite(yellow,LOW );
    digitalWrite(red,LOW );
    digitalWrite(green,HIGH );
    delay(3000);
    //if(
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What should it be doing?

Comment: The LCD won't work unless you `begin` it...

Comment: You need to provide more information. What doesn't work? Have you tried a simple sketch that just turns on one of your lights, then edit it to turn on the next, and then the last? (You need to use the simplest possible code to rule out hardware problems)

Answer (score 3):

Write a sketch to test your LCD.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 4, 2);
void setup(){
    lcd.begin();
    lcd.print("Hello World!");
}
void loop() {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Make sure the R/W pin is connected to GND on your breadboard. You may need to connect the contrast pin to 5V. Ideally it should be connected to the wiper of a 10KOhm trimpot with either end connected to GND & 5V (so you can vary the contrast).

Once that set-up works change your code

```
 void setup(){
     lcd.begin();
     lcd.print("Traffic signals");
     delay(500);
     pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop(){
     changeLights();
     lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A small update to your code

1. Added `lcd.begin();` function
2. added `lcd.clear();` function so that old characters will be removed before adding new display

Here is the complete code

```
int red = 10;
int yellow = 9;
int green = 8;
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellow, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  changeLights();
  delay(1500);
}

void changeLights() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("red");
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW );
  digitalWrite(red, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(green, LOW );
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("yellow");
  digitalWrite(yellow, HIGH );
  digitalWrite(red, LOW );
  digitalWrite(green, LOW );
  delay(3000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("green");
  digitalWrite(yellow, LOW );
  digitalWrite(red, LOW );
  digitalWrite(green, HIGH );
  delay(3000);
  //if(
}
```

The output would look like this:

[image]

[Here](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/304640214914040386) is the link to the Arduino simulator example